# I want to use http://myUrl:13001/myAppName , but I get a link to http://myUrl:13001/ and a Not Found message

Tags: grails-4

To use the URL as `http://myUrl:13001/myAppName`, the following contents are specified in the `grails-app/conf/application.yml` file.

```
environments:
    production:
        grails:
            serverURL: http://myUrl:13001/myAppName
```

To run, in grails 4.0.11
`./gradlew -Dgrails.env=prod bootRun`
command was executed.

And when I enter `http://myUrl:13001/myAppName` in the browser address bar to log in,
The login screen of `http://myUrl:13001/myAppName/` came out properly.

However, since this is the first login, after clicking the registration link, `http://myUrl:13001/myAppName/register/index` is displayed properly in the address bar.

After completing the input on the registration screen and pressing Enter,
It appears as `http://myUrl:13001//` only, and
**HTTP Status 404 - Not Found** is displayed.

Also, I made a war file and tried to run it in Tomcat made with Docker, but the same error is displayed.

I would appreciate it if you let me know if there are any other settings to add other than this

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood for a moment and asked a question.

To study grails 4, I downloaded the grails4-spring-security-login-example project from github.com.

The login form in `grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp` was as follows.

```
<form class="form-signin" action="${postUrl ?: '/login/authenticate'}" method="POST" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
```

The `'/login/authenticate'` part is hard-coded. There was no problem in the test, but I needed to set the URL to `http://myUrl:8086/myAppName` to run Tomcat.

Now I have modified that `'/login/authenticate'` part to `'/myAppName/login/authenticate'` and it is running normally.

Unfortunately, I decided to use it that way now.
I'd love to hear some advice on whether there is a better way.

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser: While it'd be a cleaner answer without the follow-up request for better solutions, this is very clearly offering an answer.